# Git (e git bash) não funciona no Windows 8

Tags: git, windows-8

Estou utilizando a ferramenta `Git` para controle de versão, utilizo o Windows 8 e o `msysgit`, após eu ter instalado, a ferramenta funcionou bem, mas logo depois, o `Git Bash` não funciona mais, como se houvesse algum problema na inicialização, e o prompt de comando não inicializa (imagem abaixo).

[image: Git bash não mostra o prompt]

Já tentei desinstalar/reinstalar o Git mas o problema persite.

Percebi que o processo do Git Bash está consumindo boa parte da memória virtual e deixando o computador bastante lento.

Comment: Só não entendi onde está a programação nessa pergunta? :S

Answer (score 2):

Um excelente console para o windows é o [cmder](http://bliker.github.io/cmder/).

Além de inúmeras configurações, ele já inclui o msysgit. Vale a pena dar uma olhada e ver se te atende.

Comment: Eu uso no Windows e é sensacional!

Answer (score 1):

Se tu quiser uma alternativa melhor que o Command Prompt e o Power Shell, utilize o *[ConEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/)*.